# Comparing few numpy arrays and getting the equal values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, compare

I'm working on Titanic dataset and after i running some algorithms i have numpy arrays of y_predictions.
I want to compare them and extract only the values that equal in each array at each place.
For example:

| index | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

a,b,c and d are y_predictions of algorithms.
The output should be:
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
Because at index 0 and 4 all the values are equal, so i assigned 1, otherwise 0.
Basically, what i want to do, is to see the indexes (passengers) which those algorithms identify as 'Survived' which represented by 1.

There is my code:

```
a= [1,1,0,0,0]
b= [1,0,0,1,0]
c= [1,1,1,0,0]
d= [1,1,0,1,0]
L= [a,b,c,d]
holder = L[0]
for i in range(len(L)):
   equality = np.where(holder == L[i+1], holder, 'None')
   holder = equ
```

But i get some errors.
I would appreciate any suggestions

Comment: try to change: range(len(L)) to range(len(L)-1) and try running your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your L array has the wrong shape you should have the transpose of your L to get the table you have in the description and I suggest you convert it to a numpy array:

```
result = []

a= [1,1,0,0,0]
b= [1,0,0,1,0]
c= [1,1,1,0,0]
d= [1,1,0,1,0]
L=np.array([a,b,c,d]).T
holder = L[0]
for i in range(len(L)):
    result.append(int(np.all(L[i,:] == L[i,0])))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in another answer, you will want to transpose your lists, and, preferably, turn them into a numpy array.

You can achieve what you want like this

```
a= [1,1,0,0,0]
b= [1,0,0,1,0]
c= [1,1,1,0,0]
d= [1,1,0,1,0]
L= np.array([a,b,c,d]).T
same_results = [len(set(col)) == 1 for col in L]

print(same_results)
# [True, False, False, False, True]
```

Comment: It works too, but the result is True or False.
Thank you

Comment: @paul booleans and integers are equivalent as truth values in python. If you want binary integers, you can simply `map` to integers or do `[int(len(set(col)) == 1) for col in L]]` or `[1 if len(set(col)) == 1 else 0 for col in L]`